# Why is there no completion pop-up for XML files?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've made some SublimeText snippets and completions for XML. While all completions work, SublimeText (I'm using v3) never shows the completion pop-up like it does with other file types. How can I enable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your user preferences (`Preferences -> Settings-User`):

```json
"auto_complete_selector": "source, meta.tag, text.xml"
```

This enables autocompletion in all source code files (Python, Ruby, etc.), in HTML/XML tags, and anywhere in XML documents.

Good luck!